# Iterate into a promise result and make many calls to other promises

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I use an external API, that I don't have access to its source. One of the endpoints, returns something like that:

```
[{
   task: '1',
   task_name: 'Do the laundries',
   project: '15',
   project_name: 'My schedule',
   user_id: '10'
},
....
]
```

Then for every object of the above, I need to call another endpoint to get the user name from the user_id and append it to the above object. The final result should be like that:

```
[{
   task: '1',
   task_name: 'Do the laundries',
   project: '15',
   project_name: 'My schedule',
   user_id: '10',
   username: 'John Doe'
},
....
]
```

Here is what I have done until now,

```
  getTasks() {  
    return this.myApi.getTasksList(this.maxResults)
      .then( (data) => {
        if ( data.status == 200 ) {
          this.tasks = data.response.entries;          
        } else {
          console.log('Something was wrong. Error status ' + data.status);
        }          
      })
      .then( (data) => {
        for ( let task of this.tasks ) {
            return this.myApi.getUsersName(task['user_id'])
              .then( result => {    
                if ( result['status'] == 200 ) {
                  task['username'] = result.response.username;
                } else {
                  console.log('Something was wrong. Error status ' + result['status']);
                }
              })
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('something was wrong: ' + err);
      });
  }
```

Both `getTasksList` and `getUsersName` return a `Promise`.

With the above, I get `this.tasks` data, but it doesn't include the `username`.

I found a similar question says that you need to create an array of Promises and call them at once. Example here:

```
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var promise = $http.get('/data' + i);
    promises.push(promise);
}
$q.all(promises).then(doSomethingAfterAllRequests);
```

However, I am not able to adapt it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things which are wrong in your code.

- You're not returning anything from the `then`, yet you're [chaining `.then` calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining).
- You're using `if/else` structure to log an error, instead of using [`Promise#catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) mechanism.
- You're returning the inside the `for` loop which means you're breaking it on the first iteration.

Since you're using Angular, you should leverage Observables. Instead of nested calls, you can use [`mergeMap` from RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

If you still want to use promises, you might find [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) easier to work with. It's fa fairy new feature in browsers, but since you're using a transpiler, you don't have to worry about browser support for it.